# Spark 2.1.1 Processing Multiple gzip/bzip2 Files in Parallel

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This is what am trying to do , I have 24 files as input, compressed in gzip format and I want to read and process all these 24 files in parallel i.e one file processed by one task and by processing I mean just read the contents of the file and repartition the data based on order_created_date and write data back to S3 (In format s3://bucket_name/order_created_date=20170701/)
But for some reason only one executor is processing the data and not sure what all other executors are doing , I tried compressing the data in bzip2 format as well but there also am observing the same behaviour i.e only one executor I can see it reading data and remaining all other executors not reading data from the respective files

My code (Scala) :

```
//Reading Data
val inputDf = spark.read.option("sep", "^").option("quote", "\"").option("compression", "bzip2").csv(paths.toSeq: _*)
//Attach Schema to Dataframe
val renamedRdd = inputDf.toDF(selectColumns.toSeq: _*)
//Repartition Input Data and Write it back to S3
renamedRdd.write.partitionBy("order_created_date").format("orc").option("compression", "zlib").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save(outputPath)
```

Please find the screen shot here : https://ibb.co/eSV2VQ

Can someone please let me know what's wrong here ? 2 days got wasted debugging it

Comment: BTW, Input files am reading them from S3 (using s3a://bucketname)

Comment: Can you show the execution timeline?

Comment: @windrunn3r.1990 here it is https://ibb.co/notBPk

Comment: if we see the status of these tasks here https://ibb.co/dCMHVQ , most of the executor were in success state without reading any data and if i check the task log , I can see the below error  :  CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
17/07/26 17:31:57 INFO DiskBlockManager: Shutdown hook called
17/07/26 17:31:57 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called

Comment: I have just now verified that the data is getting processed correctly but just that UI is showing wrong input sizes, any reason for the same?